# Условие внутри функции и не правильный вывод результата

Tags: php, функции, if

Здраствуйте. Этот код если не ошибаюсь должен выводить 1 2 3 4 5 если х равно asc и 9 8 7 6 5 если x не равно asc.

```
<?php
$x = 'asc';
function fun() 
{
    if($GLOBALS['x'] == 'asc')
    {
        static $counter = 0;
        $counter++;
        echo "$counter<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        static $counter = 10;
        $counter--;
        echo "$counter<br>";
    }
}
fun();
fun();
fun();
fun();
fun();
?>
```

Но оно выводит 11 12 13 14 15 если х равно asc и 9 8 7 6 5 если х не равно asc.
Почему условие не работает и в любом случае на counter устанавливается значение 10?

Answer (score 1):

Статические значения сохранятся между вызовами функции, поэтому такие переменные заводятся перед тем как осуществляется первый вызов функции с `fun()`.

При этом берется последнее определение статической переменной `$counter`, не обращая внимание на внутреннюю логику функции - логика начинает работать потом, при вызове. Поэтому у вас значение `$counter` у вас всегда начинается с 10.

```
static $counter = 10;
```